# How to detect multi touches in a custom keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I want to create a custom keyboard in android that is used by visually impaired people in order to write in Braille,it should have no keys at all I just want to detect multi touches on the keyboard and translate them into letters.

My question : how can I detect multitouches in OnKeyboardActionListener ?